# Set Default Value global-Filter React-Table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

I have a React-Table and using the globalFilter of React. The filtering works with the OnChange function, but i want to set a default String to my Input-Field and trigger the filtering Function.
This is my Component:

```
import React from "react";

export const GlobalFilter = ({ filter, setFilter }) => {
    
  return (
    <span>
      <input
        id="globalFilterOrderHistory"
        className="input searchHistoryOrder"
        placeholder="Search"
        value={filter || ""}
        onChange={(e) => setFilter(e.target.value)}
      />
      <i className="fa fa-search fa-1_5" />
    </span>
  );
};
```

I tried to add something like this:

```
useEffect(()=>{
       setFilter("projekt");
   })
```

The filter is now set to the String "projekt", but now I can´t type something in the InputField.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer, there should be passed a secound argument to the useEffect

```
useEffect(()=>{
       setFilter("projekt");
   },[])
```